# How to pass a static variable to a Laravel route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I try to rewrite Symfony routes to Laravel routes. The problem is that some Symfony routes take `defaults` and go the same controller. Can I add some arguments to the Laravel routes to accomplish the same?

**e.g. Symfony yaml**

```
 path: /account/
    defaults:
        _controller: "legacy.controller.fallback:Somefunt"
        pag_act: "secret"
        m_act: "home"

 path: /account2/
        defaults:
            _controller: "legacy.controller.fallback:Somefunt"
            pag_act: "public"
            m_act: "home"
```

**e.g. laravel**

```
Route::any('/account', 'SomeSymfonyController@Somefunt');
```

As you can see: the defaults for these 2 Symfony routes are different (pag_act), can I pass this in Laravel too?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Route::any('/account', 'SomeSymfonyController@Somefunt')
      ->defaults('pag_act', 'secret');

Route::any('/account2', 'SomeSymfonyController@Somefunt')
      ->defaults('pag_act', 'public');
```

and in your SomeSymfonyController `Somefunt` method

```
public function Somefunt(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->route('pag_act')); // Returns 'secret' or 'public' based on route
}
```

Comment: thanks, will test this and is probably exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Simply create another `Route::`

```
Route::any('/account', 'SomeSymfonyController@secretFunt');
Route::any('/account2', 'SomeSymfonyController@publicFunt');
```

In your SomeSymfonyController you could say this:

```
public function secretFunt()
{
    $pag_act = 'secret';
    $m_act = 'home';
}

public function publicFunt()
{
    $pag_act = 'public';
    $m_act = 'home';
}
```

---

In case `secretFunt()` does the same as `publicFunt()`, but only the `$pag_act`'s value is different: we don't want duplicate content whenever we process this `$pag_act` variable. So we can create a function for that:

```
public function funtHandler($act)
{
    $pag_act = $act;
    $m_act = 'home';
}

public function secretFunt()
{
    $pag_act = 'secret';
    $this->funtHandler($pag_act);
}

public function publicFunt()
{
    $pag_act = 'public';
    $this->funtHandler($pag_act);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the problem lies with wanting to use the same function in the controller., but this will work. Why? Because it's still shared with symfony.