# How do I define an optional parameter in my Laravel routes?

Tags: laravel

I would like to define `{id}` an optional parameter in the following route:

```
Route::get('profile/edit/{id}', array('uses' => 'BusinessController@editProfile', 'as' => 'profile.edit'));
```

How can I do this and also define a default parameter if one isn't provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Route::get('profile/edit/{id?}', array('uses' => 'BusinessController@editProfile', 'as' => 'profile.edit'));
```

you can pass `{id?}` for optional parameters in your route.

Laravel will take it as a optional. it is called as a wild card in laravel

Answer (score 1):

Just like the other answers, but as for the default part: I asked [almost the same question a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44796752/how-to-pass-a-static-variable-to-a-laravel-route) and the answer is:

```
Route::get('profile/edit/{id?}', array('uses' => 'BusinessController@editProfile', 'as' => 'profile.edit'))
    ->defaults('id', 'defaultValue');
```

The important things are

- The questionmark
- The `defaults` function

Answer (score 0):

Just put a question mark after it in the route, and give it a default in the function:

```
Route::get('profile/edit/{id?}', ...
public function editProfile ($id = 123) { ... }
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#parameters-optional-parameters